# Simple Hibernate Mapping Advice

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm going to work for a company as a JAVA Developer intern,the director gave me assignment for internship.
I have studied hibernate i'm asking this question beacuse i want to be sure about my solution correctness.

**Table 1** . `Business_Card`
id, int4 , primary key
name, varchar 50
description, varchar 250

**Table 2** . `Corresponding Business Phone 1xN`
id , int4, primary key
**business_id , int4, foreign key -> business_card table**

phone_area_code, varchar 5
phone number, varchar 15

**Table 3** . `Contact Groups`
id, int4, primary key
group name, varchar 25
group description, varchar 250

**Table 4** . `Business X Contact NxN`
id , int4, primary key
**business_id , int4, foreign key -> business_card table

group_id , int4, foreign key -> contact_groups table**

*** *business_id, group_id pair will be unique***

1. **Business Card insertion screen** , search screen.In the gui form, you will use fields in the business_card table.
2. **Business(Contact) Group insertion screen** , search screen. In the gui form, You will use fields in the business group(contact) table.
3. **Business Phone insertion screen**, search screen. In the gui form, you will use fields in the business phone table
   **NOTE**: there will be a combo box, to select the Business Card.
4. **Business Group selection screen**. In the gui form, there will be two combo boxes. One is for business card selection, and other one is for group selection. You will insert data with these pairs, to the contact_group table.

**Here is my solution:**
Between Table 2 and Table 1 there is a `One-To-Many` Relationship (Table 2(One) To Table 1(Many))

For Table 4: Between Table 1 and Table 3 there is a `Many to Many` Relationship.


***Is my Approach right for relationships between Tables?***

Also what does this sentece mean '**business_id, group_id pair will be unique**' what can i do for this rule.
Lastly,what can i use for GUI for user interface with hibernate for this task.

Comment: Well the approach seems pretty much  correct.  You can avoid id column in table 4. Also if you can add some problem statement may be we can help little bit more. Table 4 also achieves 'business_id, group_id pair will be unique' .

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems correct. I think you should remove id column from table 4. If you use hibernate mappings correctly for Many to Many you'll get this table automatically. Refer these links: [Many to many xml example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/) and [Many to Many annotations example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)

Although its up to you which GUI you want to use, i would use JSF2, it is really easy to use. You can find a tutorial [here](http://javaknowledge.info/simple-crud-using-jsf2hibernate-integration-and-mysql/) and another one with Spring [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/).

Hope it helps.